# Upper envelope of plurisubharmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, reference-request, several-complex-variables, potential-theory

Suppose that $\{u_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is a family of [plurisubharmonic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurisubharmonic_function) (psh function) on $\Omega \subset\subset \mathbb{C}^n$. Then, let $u(z) = \sup_{\alpha \in A} u_{\alpha}(z)$ be the upper envelope.

I found in lots of literature that 
$$u^\ast(z) := \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \sup_{B_{\epsilon}(z)} u(z)$$ (usc regularization)
is still a psh fucntion.

Is there any counterexample that the upper envelope $u$ for psh functions $u_\alpha$ before doing usc regulatization is not psh, I wonder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that works already for $n=1$. Let $\Omega$ be the unit disc and let
$$
u_n(z) = \frac1n \log|z|.
$$
Then
$$
u(z) = \sup_n u_n(z) = \begin{cases} 0, & z \neq 0 \\ -\infty, & z = 0, \end{cases}
$$
which is not upper semicontinuous, and therefore not (pluri-)subharmonic.

It may also be helpful to know that $u$ is "almost" psh already before the usc regularization; assuming that the family $\{ u_\alpha \}$ is locally upper bounded, then $u = u^*$ outside a pluripolar set, so in particular outside a set of Lebesgue measure $0$.